File System Access API only working for .txt file extension
I am working on a Next.js application and I am using the File System Access API to prompt the user for a folder location and create a file at that location. I have a valid FileSystemDirectoryHandle but this fails when I call a getFileHandle function on it with any extension other than .txt. This piece of code has been working for 2 weeks now creating .ini files using the getFileHandle but this week I am getting errors that say:
desLoad failed:  TypeError: Failed to execute 'getFileHandle' on 'FileSystemDirectoryHandle': Name is not allowed.

Rewritting the code like this succeeds:
desTestHandle = await newBuildingHandle.getFileHandle('desload.txt', {
   create: true,
});

While this part fails and throws an error:
desTestHandle = await newBuildingHandle.getFileHandle('desload.ini', {
   create: true,
});

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can provide on this cause I'm stumped!

Where is this running, the client or the server? If the user is selecting the file from a dialogue, how can you use a literal filename in the call?

This is running in the client and I prompt the user to select a directory which I store as the rootHandle and then I get a subfolder using the getDirectoryHandle function like this:
const newBuildingHandle = await rootHandle.getDirectoryHandle('subfolder', {       create: false,     });
It's inside of this subfolder that I am trying to create the file using getFileHandle and it succeeds for some extension types but not .ini which is what I'm trying to create.

"has been working for 2 weeks now creating .ini files using the getFileHandle but this week I am getting errors" - what changed "this week"?

From the specification: Creation can fail because there already is a directory with the same name, because the name uses characters that aren’t supported in file names on the underlying file system, or because the user agent for security reasons decided not to allow creation of the file. Maybe a browser upgrade added a "security reason" and it no longer allows this.

I think there was a Chrome upgrade a couple of days ago.

@Barmar Thanks for the responses and I have tried to look for this specifically but couldn't find anything. This failed in Edge as well but when I switched to an Opera browser it was able to create a .ini file. Still looking into it but I appreciate your help

This is still a relatively new API, so things may not have stabilized yet.

What happens if you console.log all of the tuples in FileSystemDirectoryHandle.entries() ?

@Dai I can console log out the entries() and I get a list of all the files in the folder. I placed some example files in the folder to test and I can see all the files with the following extensions: .txt, .siz, .frm, .in, .pdf but I cannot see the two files that have the extension .ini in that folder.

I am having the same issue with a .cfg file.  I filed an issue with Chromium Here.  Unfortunately this is not an issue with the API but the browser itself.  They replied that this is intended behavior and they won't fix.
